# GraphQL update and delete mutations not working

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I'm new to GraphQL and working on AWS AppSync and testing with POSTMAN

I created API and able to run createMutation and List query

Here is my schema

```
input CreateUserInput {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    gender: String!
    email: String!
    password: String!
}

input DeleteUserInput {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
}

type Mutation {
    createUser(input: CreateUserInput!): User
    updateUser(input: UpdateUserInput!): User
    deleteUser(input: DeleteUserInput!): User
}

input UpdateUserInput {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    gender: String
    email: String
    password: String
}

type User {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    gender: String!
    email: String!
    password: String!
}
```

Following works in POSTMAN:

**Query:**

```
mutation createUser($createuserinput: CreateUserInput!) {
  createUser(input: $createuserinput) {
    id
    name
    gender
    email
    password
  }
}
```

**Variables**

```
{
  "createuserinput": {
    "id": "AAAUzF6XsJUCJ7tJw0NREODencTOp6wES",
    "name": "Somename",
    "gender": "male",
    "email": "some@email",
    "password": "12345"
  }
}
```

Following is not working

**Query**

```
mutation updateUser($updateuserinput: UpdateUserInput!) {
  updateUser(input: $updateuserinput) {
    id
    name
    gender
    email
    password
  }
}
```

**Variables**

```
{
  "updateuserinput": {
    "id": "AAAUzF6XsJUCJ7tJw0NREODencTOp6wES",
    "name": "Somename2",
    "gender": "male",
    "email": "some@email2",
    "password": "123456"
  }
}
```

I get the error:

```
{
    "data": {
        "updateUser": null
    },
    "errors": [
        {
            "path": [
                "updateUser"
            ],
            "data": null,
            "errorType": "DynamoDB:ConditionalCheckFailedException",
            "errorInfo": null,
            "locations": [
                {
                    "line": 2,
                    "column": 3,
                    "sourceName": null
                }
            ],
            "message": "The conditional request failed (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ConditionalCheckFailedException; Request ID: MG0N1EP32Q7D946OU4JODOQHH7VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)"
        }
    ]
}
```

I think the id is not getting passed properly. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue.

In the mutations update and delete, the name is marked mandatory. I had to pass name as well to be able to update/delete.

Example:

```
{
  "deleteuserinput": {
    "id": "u1",
    "name": "Ashutosh Pandey"
  }
}
```

This happened when I selected **name** as the sort key while creating model

Comment: Thanks Ashutosh for the detailed question; glad you figured it out! In future, would also suggest including the request mapping template (VTL) as well, as that would indicate what is actually being sent to DynamoDB.

Comment: Sure @Aaron_H, will do in future